# UITableViewCell separator lines not appearing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableView with custom tableViewCells that are 42 high.
For some reason the separator lines are not appearing. It acts as if it is a normal tableView i.e. i can scroll and delete cells, but the separator lines are just not there.

Does anybody know why?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you've remembered to override tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You nees to set SeparatorStyle of the teble like:

```
mtable.separatorStyle= UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
```

Hope this will help u out.This has  worked for  me.

Comment: This worked but shouldn't creating the cell in the XIB handle that for me?

Comment: That's not up to the cells, but to the table view