# UITableView separator line does not show in iPhone app

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have app in which i am using tableView problem is that when tableView has one record then it does not show separator line but shows when there are two records.

The first cell in tableView is textField. here is the code i am using.

```
    for (UIView *subView in cell.subviews)
    {
    if (subView.tag == 2 || subView.tag == 22) 
    {
        [subView removeFromSuperview];
    }
    }

   tableView.backgroundView=nil;

   tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;

   tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;


   if(indexPath.section==0){

   tagInputField =[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,248,31)];



    tagInputField.contentVerticalAlignment=UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    tagInputField.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
    tagInputField.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

    tagInputField.tag = 2;
    tagInputField.delegate = self;
    tagInputField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;


    [tagInputField.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
    [tagInputField.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    tagInputField.layer.borderWidth = 0.3;
    tagInputField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;


    tagInputField.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Myriad-Pro" size:8];
    [tagInputField setText:@"Enter tag here "];
    tagInputField.textColor =[UIColor grayColor];





    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;

    [cell addSubview:tagInputField];






    return cell;



}


if(indexPath.section==1) {
    UIButton *crossButton =[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(228, 8, 18, 18)];
    crossButton.tag = 22; //use a tag value that is not used for any other subview
    //crossButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    crossButton.backgroundColor  = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cross.png"]];
    [cell addSubview:crossButton];
    cell.textLabel.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Myriad-Pro" size:8];
    cell.textLabel.textColor =[UIColor grayColor];

    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

    cell.textLabel.text =[tagArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [crossButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteCell:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    [tagInputField setFrame:CGRectMake(5,0,248,31)];


    tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];


    [tagInputField.layer setCornerRadius:0.0f];
    [tagInputField.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];


    tagInputField.layer.borderWidth = 0.0;
    tagInputField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;




    return cell;
}
```

Comment: try to add textfield in cell like [cell.contentView addSubview:tagInputField];

Comment: Your cell height may be more so it override on saperator line

Comment: try to    tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor redColor];

Answer (score 5):

When you will have only 1 record then separator will not show, and you should setting the separator for tableView at viewDidLoad look like

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
}
```

and in any case you want to show your own separator for every single cell ten try to add a imageView or somrthing witch share by the table cell

```
UIView *separatorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 43, 1024, 1)];
separatorView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
separatorView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
[cell.contentView addSubview:separatorView];
```

[How to customize tableView separator in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374990/how-to-customize-tableview-seperator-in-iphone)

go for more on it....

Comment: the same line which you gave nothing else

Answer (score 1):

Just try like this in side the Cell_for_Row_At_Index_path delegate method:

```
[tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    [tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

just paste this line and check.

Answer (score 0):

add an empty footer at the end of the tableview to show the separator. To do so implement the following tableview delegate method in your class with your other tableview delegate functions:

`-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 0.001;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I used this to add last cell separator line....

```
  - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
        {
            return 1.0f;
        }

        - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
        {
            // To "clear" the footer view
            UIView *separatorLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 43, 1024, 1)];
            separatorLine.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
            separatorLine.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
            return separatorLine;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found none of the above answers worked. I was particularly wary of the answer suggesting adding a UIView to look like the line.

In the end I found that this answer worked for me:

```
tableView.separatorStyle= UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
```

In another answer it was suggested that adding worked better

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
tableView.separatorStyle= UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
```

but I found that this was unnecessary.

All the credit goes to [user859045](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457865/uitableviewcell-separator-lines-not-appearing) and [samvermette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924589/uitableviewcell-separator-disappearing-in-ios7) for their answers on different threads. samvermette's thread especially has a lot of answers on this topic which are very helpful and worth a look.